# Why do <fieldset>s clear floats?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float, fieldset

Consider the following test case, in which a floated and an inline element are placed inside a `<fieldset>` versus a `<div>`:

```css
.float {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>With fielset</h1>
<fieldset>
  <span>Inline!</span>
  <div class="float">Float!</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <span>Inline!</span>
  <div class="float">Float!</div>
</fieldset>

<h1>With div</h1>
<div>
  <span>Inline!</span>
  <div class="float">Float!</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Inline!</span>
  <div class="float">Float!</div>
</div>
```

When rendered, `fieldset` containers are 200 pixels tall (they clear the floats?) while the `div` containers are only as tall as the inline elements. What is the cause of this behavior, and is there a workaround which allows the `fieldset` containers to behave as the `div` containers do?

Comment: if you DON'T want them to clear floats, try giving the fieldset a style of `clear: none`

Comment: Had to get on the computer just to see what Jared Farrish was trying to show in his fiddle... turns out he was just playing the fiddle for the OP instead of showing proof otherwise.

Comment: @DA @imoda: I am pretty sure the default clearing style for fieldsets is already `clear: none`.

Comment: @BoltClock - I hope you weren't too disappointed... :P

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Well at least I'm not stubbornly browsing on my iPhone anymore this morning, so thanks :)

Comment: @Matt - I assume you're after something more like this, only with fieldsets? http://jsfiddle.net/HH5An/1/

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yes, I'm trying to get a fieldset which acts like a div in this respect. The context doesn't matter; this will be part of a more complicated page, but I was trying to make the test case as simple as possible.

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes, the default for fieldsets is clear:none. Chrome's web inspector shows the fieldsets and divs' computed styles to be equivalent in every way except for dimensions (and maybe margins and padding).

Comment: maybe fieldset is not what you want, try using a div, and add the css formating of fieldset, without the clear property of course

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently `<fieldset>` elements [are supposed to generate block formatting contexts for their contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements):

> The `fieldset` element is expected to establish a new block formatting context.

[That's why floated elements don't float out of them.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) I would guess that this has to do with the nature of fieldsets as visual form control groups. There could be other reasons, but off the top of my head that sounds the most plausible.

There doesn't appear to be a way to undo this, but I wouldn't be surprised; you can't destroy a block formatting context after creating it.

---

By the way, `<fieldset>`s don't *clear* floats (unless you give them a `clear` style of something other than `none`). When an element clears floats (or is said to have clearance), it clears only the *preceding* floats that touch it within the same formatting context. A parent element doesn't clear its children's floats either, but it can establish a formatting context for them to float in. This is the behavior seen with `<fieldset>`, and it's also what happens when you set `overflow` to something other than `visible` on a parent element.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control) (emphasis mine):

> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may *not* be adjacent to an earlier floating box. **The 'clear' property does not consider floats inside the element itself or in other [block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)**.

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, there is no clearing style defined by browsers for that element, so the default clearing style would already be the default value of `none`. This is shown in this demo, in which only one of the `<fieldset>`s coming after the floating box is defined to have clearing properties and is indeed the one clearing the float.

```css
.float {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.clear {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="float">Float!</div>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fieldset!</legend>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="clear">
  <legend>Clearing fieldset!</legend>
</fieldset>
```

[External link of the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/uD2C8)

Comment: I certainly couldn't figure out a way to do it either.

Comment: The weirdest thing about this is that it was only in the HTML5 spec that `fieldset`s were defined to be their own BFCs. It wasn't in the HTML 4 or CSS specs...

Comment: I guess in a way it does make sense (and I've always thought the non-clearing div thing was wonky), since you would expect a fieldset to contain in height all children. Maybe the earlier specs don't include it because the browser makers just did it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. This does, indeed, look like a case of "it's always been done this way": http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/110974. Looks like I'm going to have to look for a different way to do my layout.

Answer (score -1):

Set height for wrapper div;

```
 <html>
 <head>    
  <style type="text/css">       
   .float {float:right; background-color:red;             height:200px;}   
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body>    
 <fieldset>    
   <span>Inline!</span>    
   <div class="float">Float!</div>  
 </fieldset> 
 <fieldset>     
    <span>Inline!</span>      
   <div class="float">Float!</div>
 </fieldset> 

  <div style="height:200px">    
   <span>Inline!</span>     
  <div class="float">Float!</div> </div> 
 <div style="height:200px">     
 <span>Inline!</span>    
 <div class="float">Float!</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you're quite following what Matt is after with the fieldsets (not the divs).

Comment: This is an acceptable way to make the divs behave as the fieldsets do (I could also use one of the numerous float-clearing methods that exist), but I'm looking for a solution which makes the fieldsets behave as the divs do.