# Parent Height doesn't follow their float children

Tags: css, css-float

My mainContainer height doesn't follow their children width

and here is my code do you have any suggestion please advise.

I need the CSS solution not JavaScript so thank in advance

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="leftContent">

    </div>

    <div id="rightContent">

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
#mainContainer{
    width: 1000px;
    /*height: 1000px;*/
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#leftContent{
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    background-color: violet;
}
#rightContent{
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    width: 620px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You could apply a clearfix to the element. Your height of parent won't adjust to floating elements standardly.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to the container:

```
#mainContainer{
    width: 1000px;
    /*height: 1000px;*/
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    overflow: hidden; /* <--- here */
}
```

Because its content is floated, the container div collapses. Using a 'clearfix' class or, as I mentioned, adding `overflow:hidden` will cause the container to contain the floated elements.

**UPDATE** Explanation of why this works can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9193270/1588648

... and here:

> In order for them (browsers) to calculate what overflowed the bounds of the block (and thus should be hidden), they needed to know the size of the block. Because these blocks do no have an explicit height set, the browsers used the calculated height of the content instead.

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

Comment: WOW That Save my life. I have sit for 3 hours for nothing Thank a lot @Kevin Boucher

Comment: But can you describe more about why overflow:hidden solve this issue how the way it make a container to contain the floats.

Comment: @JongzPuangput Never found a satisfactory answer to why this works. Here's a couple of articles: http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/ http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: What if overflow hidden is not an option (because content is below the window and not visible (and also not scrollable)). Adding `:after` and `clear:both`also doesn't work

Comment: @NicolasV If you can recreate the issue in jsfiddle or somewhere, I can take a look at it.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Kev, sorry but my issue was rather urgent, had to find another solution fast so I changed some stuff around.. Initial project isn't mine so I didn't quite understand the code very well. Thx anyway

Comment: I know this is old but I have the problem now myself and was searching for solutions. In the container add an empty div tag with clear:both. It will clear the previous floats and thus the container will wrap around its children.

Comment: I could kiss you.  I had the following layout with flexbox elements and floated images:

[section] > [container] > [column] > [floated image]

I was noticing the image's parents weren't collapsing in IE 11.  Setting 'overflow: hidden' on the section, container, and column elements did the trick!

Answer (score 12):

You need to clear your floating elements, use `overflow: hidden;` for `#mainContainer`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YmbjV/)**

Alternate : (You can add `clear: both;` to clear floats)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmbjV/1/)

Or you can also self clear floating elements (Only if you wish to support IE9=+

```
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

[Why this happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734)

Comment: That's how it should be done! `overflow: hidden` could... well.. just hide content.

Answer (score 4):

Use overflow: hidden and clear a float

```
#mainContainer{
    width: 1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```