# What effect does overflow:hidden has in this code?

Tags: html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Why when `overflow:hidden` is added in `.navbar` it works and without it the left side is white and the text is on the right side? Also, how and what is the purpose of applying `overflow` here when this is what I read about the attribute:

> Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a
>   specified height.

Answer (score 2):

It's all because of [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)
If you remove `overflow: hidden` everything for that element appears on left because children elements have `float` property and there is no place where `float` is cleared.

For *block formatting context* you can refer this answer [Why does overflow hidden stop floating elements escaping their container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193214/why-does-overflow-hidden-stop-floating-elements-escaping-their-container)

Also please refer : [Parent Height doesn't follow their float children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493456/parent-height-doesnt-follow-their-float-children)

Comment: Why does float need to be cleared in this example when we want them to be on the left? If we clear the float we'll get the elements stacked one over another. Thanks.

Comment: You can read more of clearing floats [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do). I have created a fiddle for reference with the mentioned example. https://jsfiddle.net/3dw9y040/ Please check I have added `<div class="clear"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you remove overflow:hidden from the navbar, it makes the menu items disappear because there is no background in `.navbar` at that time and both a and button tags has `color: fff;` which is same as page background color.

**Now, why we need overflow:hidden; in .navbar**

Its because all the child inside `.navbar` has **float** property associated with them and floated elements don't take any space in normal document flow. Now if the child elements are not taking any space then the height property for parent (`.navbar`) is 0.

To maintain the height property of parent class when child classes are floated, we use `overflow: hidden;` property

Hope it help

Comment: If the parent has height 0, why does it matter when the children have height?