# Margin-Bottom from outer DIV does not work

Tags: html, css, margin

I'd like to create an outer DIV, which contains several inner DIVs. At the moment, this works perfect.
But I have some troubles with the margin of the outer div. If the outer DIV has a fixed height (f.ex. height: 100px;), there will be a margin at the bottom. But if I set the height to auto (it should have only the height of all inner DIVs), the margin-bottom disappears.

Example:

Here, the margin-bottom applies normaly. The height of the outer-box is set to a fixed height:
https://jsfiddle.net/v81mehc5/3/

But changing the height of the outer DIV from a fixed height (75px) to auto, the margin-bottom of 40px disappears.
https://jsfiddle.net/v81mehc5/2/

What's missing in the second case? What's wrong overthere?

HTML

```
text before

<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="innerbox-left">left</div>
  <div class="innerbox-right">right</div>
  <div class="innerbox-left">left</div>
  <div class="innerbox-right">right</div>
</div>

text after
```

CSS

```
.outer-box
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px; /*if height: auto > no margin-bottom will be applied*/
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: thin dotted #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.innerbox-left
{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.innerbox-right
{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: no, it's not a case of collapsing margins. Temani Afif in answer below is right, OP missed to clear after floated elements.

Comment: @panther yes, I realise that - now. Thank you :)

Comment: @dippas like panther i don't agree with this duplication as it's related to floating and not collapsing margin. Maybe another duplication but not this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is missing but you are using **floating elements** inside the outer div. So `height:auto` means `height:0` in you case so you are only seeing the margin-bottom (that you thought it's the height).

[image]

In order to fix this you need to add `overflow:hidden` to outer div.

```css
.outer-box
{
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: thin dotted #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.innerbox-left
{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.innerbox-right
{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
text before

<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="innerbox-left">left</div>
  <div class="innerbox-right">right</div>
  <div class="innerbox-left">left</div>
  <div class="innerbox-right">right</div>
</div>

text after
```

More questions related to the same issue for more details :

[Why does overflow hidden stop floating elements escaping their container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193214/why-does-overflow-hidden-stop-floating-elements-escaping-their-container)

[CSS overflow:hidden with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats)

Comment: Great answer, great solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Floating elements collapse their container. You'll see that if you apply a border to it:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #666; margin-bottom: 40px;">
<div style="float: left; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 49%;"></div>
<div style="float: right; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 49%;"></div>
</div>
Text
```

You can use a clearing technique to get around this as a possible solution that works in IE8 and up:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
  .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #666; margin-bottom: 40px;" class="clearfix">
<div style="float: left; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 49%;"></div>
<div style="float: right; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 49%;"></div>
</div>
Text
```