# Floating fieldset with same height

Tags: html, css

I've this code:

```
<div id="container">
 <fieldset class="box">
  <legend>Title</legend>
   CONTENT
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="box">
  [etc...]
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I would like to have these fieldsets with the same height and floating.

So I've set the container with `display:table` and each fieldset with `display:table-cell` but, if I use `float:left` to floating each box (fieldset), `display:table-cell` doesn't work anymore.

This should be the result:

[image: Result]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why would you `float` a table cell? Use `display: inline-block`. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/j2jRb/)

Comment: Sorry what? I write the correct answer and you give it to someone else? Where did you say anything about using `jQuery` in your question. You tagged it as `HTML` and `CSS`. Next time make your question more clear on tools we can use to fix the problem. Not even a +1, psh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using simple jQuery code you can achieve the equal column height**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bV8vn/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT
        <br/>test</fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {        
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var H = 0;
    $("div").each(function (i) {
        var h = $(".box").eq(i).height();
        if (h > H) H = h;
    });
    $(".box").height(H);
});
```

Comment: Just to let you know, there's no reason to have `display: table-cell` there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will create an answer. So put it simply, `display: table-cell` cannot be used with `fieldset`. Find out more [**in this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203561/fieldset-does-not-support-display-table-table-cell)

You could just use `div` and change the look a little bit. Or just use them as containers for each.

But I would recommend using `display: inline-block` for this.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/j2jRb/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

And this is how you could create containers around them to be able to use `display: table;` etc.

### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="innercon">
        <fieldset class="box">
            <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="innercon">
        <fieldset class="box">
            <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="innercon">
        <fieldset class="box">
            <legend>Title</legend>CONTENT</fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table;
}
.innercon {
    display: table-cell;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/j2jRb/2/)