# <fieldset> styling not working

Tags: html, css

Styling `<fieldset>` is working oddly. In Google Chrome the divs are fit to content.

```css
.table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
</fieldset>
```

whereas what I want is

```css
.table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
</div>
```

How can I style `<fieldset>` to look like this latter one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203561/fieldset-does-not-support-display-table-table-cell

Comment: Adding width( say width: 100px; ) to the fieldset cell class will give what you want. But I'm still trying to understand why width : 33%; has no impact

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting the width of the fieldset to 100%, you are making the width of the border of the fieldset to `100%`. It'll not change the width of the `div`(s) inside it. So you need to style the `div`(s) which are inside the `fieldset` tag.

```css
.table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100vw * 1/3);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Certainly the best solution

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that floating the fieldset cell divs inside another div can get there

```css
 .table {
 border: none;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 display: table;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 table-layout: fixed;
 }

 .father{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 }

 .cell {
 background: #ccc;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 30%;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
 }
```

```html
 <fieldset class="table">
     <div class="father">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 31em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
   <div class="cell">2</div>  
   <div class="cell">3</div>
</fieldset>
```