# Setting height to auto

Tags: html, css

I have a div named 'post-wrap'. I have the height for this div set to auto. But, for some reason, I cannot get it to grow when content is added. What am I doing wrong? Does it have to do with the floats?

http://jsfiddle.net/h8gSV/

Answer (score 0):

Your parent element, `post-top` has its height fixed at 50px.

Comment: If something has a fixed height then it won't grow when content inside it won't fit. Hence "fixed".

Comment: @user1643248, You probably want to try setting a `min-height`.

Comment: @user1643248 I think that you meant to put the content outside the #post-top, as it was supposed to be like a post header, right? You'll have or to remove it from there, or remove the fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a height to `#post-top`, which encloses all other elements. Thus your height is always `50px`. And yes you need to clear the floats:

```
#post-top {
    width: 580px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: OR remove the content from inside the #post-top, which I think makes more sense to him.

Comment: That's different from clearing the floats. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481944/why-do-fieldsets-clear-floats/6482054#6482054 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t/12783114#12783114

Comment: @BoltClock OK; nice info – nonetheless it has the same effect as adding any other clear-fix hack…

Comment: @Derik Maybe, but this is a CSS question and I wont speculate about what the authors intent s where, unless he/she posts them…

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clearfix class to `#post-wrap` and remove the `height:50px` from `#post-user`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/rH4h5/