# How do i make a fieldset `display: block; overflow: auto` show a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I want my `<fieldset>` elements to behave like vanilla `<div>`'s by filling their containing element and showing a scrollbar when they are set to `overflow: auto`.

For instance, I don't see why the fieldset in [this
example](http://codepen.io/aaronj1335/pen/JEFmi) is wider than its containing div:

```
<div class=outer>
  <fieldset class=inner>
      fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner>
    fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
  </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding css:

```
.outer {
  width: 60px;
}

.inner {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out the culprit (in some cases) was the user-agent stylesheet in webkit was setting:

```
fieldset {
  min-width: -webkit-min-content;
}
```

[setting `min-width: 0;`](http://codepen.io/aaronj1335/pen/Iiqkx) in the stylesheet corrected the issue in Chrome 27, Safari 6.0.2, and WebKit Nightly r146031. It fails to correct the issue in Chrome 25 and FireFox 19.0.2.

Either way this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @aaronstacy: you cannot accept your answer ;-) because it does not work in Firefox

Comment: @ExplosionPills this does work for me in chrome, they are the same width, save for the fieldset's UA stylesheet-defined margin/padding.

Comment: @WalterTross true, i'm taking a closer look at that now.

Comment: @ExplosionPills i was seeing it work in chrome 27, Safari, and WebKit Nightly bulds, but you're correct it's not working in chrome 25 (stable). at least on Mac OS X. i can't figure out a way to make it work on FireFox either. this is stupid. i'll probably accept your answer, but just go with `<div class=fieldset>` in my app.

Answer (score 2):

`<fieldset>` does not inherit the width from the parent div.  The `.inner` div *does* inherit the width and shinks.  You can solve this just by adding `width: inherit` as a rule to `.inner`.  Note that `<fieldset>` may also get some extra padding and margin.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fxjek

Comment: Widths are never inherited by any element by default. The `div.inner` is being *constrained* to the width of its parent, but it itself does not *inherit* `width: 60px` from its parent. Also, specifying `width: inherit` doesn't appear to make a difference on Firefox.

Comment: @BoltClock maybe not by default, but can you explain the behavior of the `.inner` div having 58px width without any additional rule?

Comment: Since there are 1px borders on all sides, the height and width are constrained to 58px in order for it to fit in its parent.

Comment: @Boltclock why doesn't the fieldset get constrained?

Comment: That I can't explain - fieldsets are a strange beast when it comes to CSS.

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's because of the `min-width: -webkit-min-content'`, as i gave in my answer. your solution is close, but by setting `min-width` to 0, it behaves much more like a regular div.

Comment: @aaronstacy your solution does not work for me in Chrome.  I don't see the `min-width` rule in Chrome either.

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry, i commented before seeing the thread on my answer. i'll continue discussion up there.

Comment: @BoltClock just out of curiosity, do you know if `<fieldset>`'s layout specified differently in a spec somewhere? it seems like they'd just be the same as `<div>`'s

Comment: @aaronstacy: All I know is that fieldsets establish their own block formatting contexts in HTML5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481944/why-do-fieldsets-clear-floats/6482054#6482054 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-fieldset-element-0. However I don't think this contributes to the effect that you see, because `div.inner` also creates its own BFC due to the `overflow: auto` property in your code, yet it looks different from the fieldset.

Comment: @BoltClock thnx for the info!

Comment: @aaronstacy: No problem. There may be other browser-specific quirks at play, but I can't comment further.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your `fieldset` or make it like the `div` below it in your example, add the following css::

```
fieldset{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px
}
```

you need to reset the margin and padding first to act like the div below it then add the width you want :

```
.inner {    
    width:60px;    
}
```

Comment: the problem is i *want* the fieldset to behave like a div by expanding to the width of its containing element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Fieldset version is wider than the div version is because
fieldset has its own default padding unless you specify otherwise.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/RDVY7/

I added this to your CSS:

```
fieldset {
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0 ;
}
```

and it fixed the problem. If you want spacing between your fieldset version
and your div, just adjust the `margin:` element.

Comment: in the codepen i supplied the fieldset is drastically larger than the div. it's not just a margin/padding issue, it is because the div is clamped to its containing element, and the fieldset is growing beyond it. you can see that it's much more than margin/padding by inspecting the element in firebug or chrome dev tools.