# How do I float these fieldsets?

Tags: css, fieldset

I am working with an existing system, and am trying to modify the CSS in order to arrange the three columns correctly.

What css changes do I need to make in order to display the third column correctly?

### [View in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3gRd/)

**CSS**

```
.test .repeater {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.test .indent1 .wizard-parentcontrol .controlkl {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.test .wizard-controls .indent1 .control:first-child {
    margin-top: 17px;
}
.test .indent1 .wizard-parentcontrol .popupbrowser {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test wizard-parentcontrol">
    <div>
        <div>
            <fieldset></fieldset>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <div class="repeater indent1">
                            <div class="wizard-parentcontrol">
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="controlkl">Column 1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <div id="p0t2c4dpopupbrowserControl" class="popupbrowser">Column 2</div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="">
                                            <p class="ctrlinvalidmessage"></p>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div id="p0t2c5dpopupbrowserControl" class="popupbrowser">Column 3</div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My fiddle won't work. Do I need to have an account in order to save my changes to existing fiddles?

Comment: Ooh, that's my fiddle! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481944/why-do-fieldsets-clear-floats/6482054#6482054 You should be able to use the Fork button to save your own fork of it with your changes.

Comment: just curious, is it necessary for all those empty div's? Can I modify the html?

Comment: @HeHui - sorry about the empty divs. I left them in there while debugging, they are not empty in the code, but feel free to delete them.

Comment: @user12804 for what purpose are you using those <fieldset>'s ?

Comment: @Saurabh they actually do have classes/ids inside them, I just stripped them out for debugging purposes. The divs are generated by the CMS and cannot be removed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check If you can do the following changes.
I just added class

```
  .wizard-parentcontrol div
  {
     float:left;
  }
```

and removed the hardcoded width's of 33% and 30% from your code.

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/p3gRd/2/)

Comment: Thank you @Saurabh - for some reason when I implement it in the css for my CMS it doesn't look right in IE :(, but looks ok in FF

Comment: check the `clear:both` css property of css.Appying it to the next main element should work..

Comment: in IE the Second column is not on the same line as the first column, and is right aligned. The third column is also on a third line, and also right aligned...